# How to detect when a NSURLConnection has finished

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to use `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` to get a small bit of data (around 50 bytes) from a web API. I'm pretty sure the code below is right, but how do I actually get the received data and detect when its all downloaded?

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set yourself as the delegate and the connection will send you calls as it goes.
example:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 5):

By implementing **NSURLConnectionDelegate**, you can get the data in `connection:didReceiveData:` method and the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method will be called when the the operation is over. Meanwhile , `connection:didFailWithError:` will be called if there is some error during the operation.

Comment: Documentation page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegate's methods, read the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate